# Checkbox not getting selected although it does not show error while running the test case.Can someoone give suggesstions to get a solution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

By locator :Can someone give suggestions to get this resolved

```
 By ihaveoption2wheeler = By.xpath("//div[@id='twoWheelVehicles']/input[@type='checkbox']");
```

Test Page has the test case:

```
@DataProvider

public Object[][] selectcheckbox()

{
    Object[][] data = ExcelUtil.getTestData(AppConstants.checkbox_select);

    return data;
}
@Test(priority=1,dataProvider="selectcheckbox")

public void clickoncheckbox(String ihave)

{
    dropdownpage.selectihaveoption(ihave);
}
```

Page contains the method where the by locator is defined

```
public void selectihaveoption(String checkboxoption)

    {
        elementutils.waitforElement(ihaveoption);

        elementutils.clickoncheckboxradiobutton(ihaveoption,checkboxoption);
    }

                       Utils:

public void clickoncheckboxradiobutton(By locator,String value)

    {

    List<WebElement> opts = driver.findElements(locator);

     int sizeofcheckbox =  opts.size();

     for(int i=0;i<opts.size();i++)

     {
         if(opts.equals(value))

         {
             opts.get(i).click();
         }
     }
     }
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="twoWheelVehicles" class="col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

            <input id="bicycle-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bicycle">&nbsp;Bicycle  

            <input id="tricycle-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Tricycle" disabled="">&nbsp;Tricycle   

            <input id="bike-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Bike">&nbsp;Bike 

<div id="fourWheelVehicles" class="col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

            <input id="hatchback-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle4"  value="Hatchback">&nbsp;Hatchback       

            <input id="sedan-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle5" value="Sedan">&nbsp;Sedan
                <input id="van-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle6" value="Van">&nbsp;Van

            <input id="suv-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle7" value="SUV">&nbsp;SUV

            <input id="truck-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle8" value="Truck">&nbsp;Truck    

        </div>
```

Comment: Do you get an error saying that the xpath is wrong?

Comment: no it ran and passed without checking the checkbox

Comment: So it means that the xpath is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: xpath  not  sure  could be also but trying to find out this is the xpath:By ihaveoption2wheeler = By.xpath("//div[@id='twoWheelVehicles']/input[contains(text(),'')]");  now it is selecting all the options in the checkbox although have given only 2 options in the excel any inputs

Comment: Try out this xpath: ```"//*div[@id='twoWheelVehicles']/input[@type='checkbox']"```

Comment: i actually added this xpath earlier but it selects all the values any other inputs

Comment: Something is better than nothing XD. Jokes apart. Which checkbox do u want to click? I mean which number? The first or the second?

Comment: ok two wheelers has 3 options and 4 wheelers has 4 options. excel have given bicycle  for two wheelers and van and sedan for 4 wheelers..basically both the combinations

Comment: Do u definitely wanna use xpaths? I recommend u to use css selectors instead of xpaths.

Comment: not sure how to use css in this case

Comment: It's actually very simple. Open the inspect element tab. Click on the element that u want. Perform a right click. Then click copy > css selector.

Comment: no i know that but in this case i want to make it dynamic

Comment: so cannot use css iam reading from the excel and can change the values .... so any other inputs pls

Answer (score 0):

The IF loop criteria is not correct. Try this,

```
for(int i=0;i<opts.size();i++)

     {
         if(opts.get(i).gettext().equals(value))

         {
             opts.get(i).click();
         }
     }
```